# C# windows Form Obtener la version que hay en produccion con OneClick

Tags: c#

Cuando intento capturar la versión que tengo en producción de la sigueinte forma:

```
this.lbVersion.Text = String.Format(this.lbVersion.Text, version.Major, version.Minor, version.Build, version.Revision);
```

Obtengo al versión que hay en Assembly en el fichero AssemblyInfo

```
    [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Pero yo quiero obtener la version en produccion con OneClick, que es diferent a la versión de Assembly
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBKjv.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta hacer lo siguiente, si te fijas se pregunta primero si la aplicación esta implementada, para obtener la versión que deseas, si no esta implementada entonces obtener la versión del `Assembly`, por si ocurre alguna excepción, o error.

```
private string getVersion()
{
    try
    {
        if (System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
            return System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.ToString();
        else
            return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
    }
}
```

La usas así:

```
this.lbVersion.Text = $"Versión: {getVersion()}";
```

**Nota:** Es importante que tengas en cuenta que si no estas ejecutando la aplicación implementada en la pc de un cliente, no verás la versión real que deseas obtener, es decir, esto:
`System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.ToString();` solo funcionará si realmente la aplicación está instalada en el cliente.

---

**Referencia Microsoft:**
[ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.currentdeployment?view=netframework-4.8)

> La propiedad estática CurrentDeployment es válida solo desde dentro de una aplicación que se implementó con ClickOnce. Los intentos de llamar a esta propiedad desde aplicaciones que no sean ClickOnce generarán una excepción. Si está desarrollando una aplicación que se puede implementar o no con ClickOnce, use la propiedad IsNetworkDeployed para probar si el programa actual es una aplicación ClickOnce.

Comment: Mil gracias ahora si funciona.